# Failed to convert parameter value from a HashSet`1 to a IEnumerable`1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a User DefinedTable-Value Type Parameter in Stored Proc I can Run Stored Proc Successfully, But While calling it from Code I am recieving this Error.

> Failed to convert parameter value from a HashSet`1 to a IEnumerable`1.

I have tried the other similar question but did not find any solution please help me out with this.

Stored PROC

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateRole
@BusinessId INT,
@Id INT,
@Name NVARCHAR(500)=NULL,
@Description  NVARCHAR(500)=NULL,
@IsActive BIT=NULL,
@FeatureIds AS dbo.ParameterList READONLY
AS


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Business WHERE Id = @BusinessId)
    THROW 50000, N'Business not found', 1;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Role] WHERE Id = @Id and BusinessId=@BusinessId)
    THROW 50001, N'Role not found', 1;

IF EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM @FeatureIds fi
LEFT JOIN Feature f ON fi.parameter = f.Id
WHERE f.Id is NULL)
    THROW 50002, N'Feature not found', 1;

IF( (SELECT DISTINCT count(*)
                FROM BusinessPersona bp
                INNER JOIN Persona p ON bp.PersonaId = p.Id
                INNER JOIN Business b ON bp.BusinessId = b.Id
                INNER JOIN BusinessFeatureSet bfs ON b.Id = bfs.BusinessId
                INNER JOIN FeatureSet fs ON bfs.FeatureSetId = fs.Id
                INNER JOIN FeatureSetFeature fsf ON fs.Id = fsf.FeatureSetId
                INNER JOIN Feature f ON fsf.FeatureId = f.Id
                INNER JOIN @FeatureIds fi on fi.parameter=f.Id
                WHERE bp.BusinessId = @BusinessId)<(select count(*) from @FeatureIds)
)
THROW 50003, N'Forbidden Access', 1;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN_UPDATE_ROLE

            UPDATE [ROLE] SET
            [Name]=@Name,
            [IsActive]=@IsActive,
            [Description]=@Description,
            ModifiedDate = GETUTCDATE()
            WHERE Id=@Id
            AND
            (
                ISNULL([Name],'')!= COALESCE(@Name, [Name], '') or
                ISNULL([Description],'')!=COALESCE(@Description, [Description], '') or
                [IsActive]!=COALESCE(@IsActive,IsActive,'')
            );

            DELETE FROM RoleFeature where RoleId=@Id;

            INSERT INTO RoleFeature (RoleId, FeatureId)
             SELECT DISTINCT  @Id, f.Id 
                FROM BusinessPersona bp
                INNER JOIN Persona p ON bp.PersonaId = p.Id
                INNER JOIN Business b ON bp.BusinessId = b.Id
                INNER JOIN BusinessFeatureSet bfs ON b.Id = bfs.BusinessId
                INNER JOIN FeatureSet fs ON bfs.FeatureSetId = fs.Id
                INNER JOIN FeatureSetFeature fsf ON fs.Id = fsf.FeatureSetId
                INNER JOIN Feature f ON fsf.FeatureId = f.Id
                INNER JOIN @FeatureIds fi on fi.parameter=f.Id
                WHERE bp.BusinessId = @BusinessId

        

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    THROW 
    print 'rollback'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH

Go
```

Code

```
public async Task UpdateRole(Role updateRole)
    {
        var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
        {
            new SqlParameter("@BusinessId", updateRole.BusinessId),
            new SqlParameter("@Id", updateRole.Id),
            new SqlParameter("@Name", updateRole.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Description", updateRole.Description ?? (object)DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@IsActive", updateRole.IsActive ?? (object)DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter
            {
                SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured,
                Direction=ParameterDirection.Input,
                ParameterName="@FeatureIds",
                TypeName="[dbo].[ParameterList]",
                Value=updateRole.RoleFeatures
            },
        };

        await GetBusinessesQueries.FromSqlRaw("EXEC UpdateRole @BusinessId, @Id, @Name, @Description, @IsActive, @FeatureIds",
            parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
    }
```

After Executing the below method I am getting

> "Failed to convert parameter value from a HashSet`1 to a IEnumerable`1."

this error

Comment: And the error really says `HashSet\`1` rather than a specfic type?

Comment: yes it says Failed to convert parameter value from a HashSet`1 to a IEnumerable`1.

Comment: It seems likely that the issue is within `GetBusinessesQueries.FromSqlRaw` which isn't provided here. Please also provide the full stack trace along with the exception message.

Comment: It is just a virtual DbSet          public virtual DbSet<GetBusinessesQuery> GetBusinessesQueries { get; set; }

Comment: Have you tried converting your updateRole.RoleFeatures to a DataTable?

Comment: You cannot pass an `IEnumerable` to a TVP like that, you need either a `DataTable` or `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. You are not actually selecting anything in that procedure, so not sure what result you expected. Aside: `BEGIN CATCH    THROW     print 'rollback'    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;    END CATCH` doesn't make sense. If you `THROW` then the rollback won't happen, but any case you shouldn't catch and rollback yourself, just `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and the server will rollback automatically.

Comment: @Llama `FromSqlRaw` is a standard EF function to execute queries directly

Comment: @Charlieface For me, it wasn't clear if `GetBusinessesQueries` was an EF object or from a class wrapping around that. perhaps mutating the input / output.